# How to make VS Code recognize nested gradle projects?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, visual-studio-code

I cloned below git repo:

[github.com/PacktPublishing/Hands-On-Microservices-with-Spring-Boot-and-Spring-Cloud](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Hands-On-Microservices-with-Spring-Boot-and-Spring-Cloud)

I have installed latest Java and Spring extensions pack. When I open a new folder pointing to one of the folder for example Chapter09, it correctly recognizes 3 nested projects: api, util, eureka-server, but fails to recognize several nested projects under nested microservices folder. At the root level there is settings.gradle that defines all the nested gradle projects. Here is the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

In eclipse it works fine but I need to use VS Code.

Answer (score 3):

I saw these messages in the Problems view (e.g. project product-composite-service not being able to resolve its dependency on the api project):[image]

Try removing settings.gradle from folders

```
microservices\product-composite-service
microservices\product-service
microservices\recommendation-service
microservices\review-service
```

and then reimport the projects (via command Java: Import Java projects in workspace).